# Efficiency of tf.gradients()

Tags: tensorflow

The code below measures the gradient of a linear model `y = X0*X1*X2` where `X0,...` are matrices of rank 5000. The gradient is measured in two ways, determined by `combined`:

1. With a single gradients call `tf.gradients(y, [x0, x1, ...])`
2. With several gradients calls `tf.gradients(y, x0), ...`

My expectation was that method 1 would be much faster than method 2, because it is able to use back propagation and share results between the different 'layers' (different matrices in this case). I thought method 2 cannot do this and has to compute the gradient from scratch for each layer.

In fact the running times are almost equal (both for CPU and GPU), and they scale the same way when changing the rank. Why is that?

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

depth = 3
rank = 5000
combined = False

def get_matrix(rank):
    return np.random.rand(rank, rank).astype(np.float32)

xs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(rank, rank)) for i in range(depth)]
feed = {x: get_matrix(rank) for x in xs}

y = xs[0]
for i in range(1, depth):
    y = tf.matmul(y, xs[i], name='mul{}'.format(i))

if combined:
    # Method 1
    g = tf.gradients(y, xs)
else:
    # Method 2
    g = [tf.gradients(y, x) for x in xs]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Warmup
for i in range(3):
    sess.run(g, feed_dict=feed)

start = time()
result = sess.run(g, feed_dict=feed)
print('Combined:' if combined else 'Separate:', time() - start, 'secs')
```